# How can I reload once using window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJs for my web application and I got problems with my login, the only solution that I found is reloading the page after login, but I need only once, but now is an infinite loop. How can I use `Window.location.reload()` only once

Login Method:

```
.success(function (data) {

        $scope.tokengenerated = data.token;

        $cookies.put('Username', UsernameValue);

        $cookies.put('Token', $scope.tokengenerated);

        $location.path("/incidents");
})
```

Comment: show your code. what is invoking it?

Comment: what's on your `/incidents` view??

Comment: When I do login and try to go to my Index, angular doesn't detect my cookies at the first load, I need to reload my page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading the page for the first time, do it like this:

```
wwww.example.com/incidents?reload=true
```

Then check if the parameter is there:

```
if (location.search.indexOf("reload=true") != -1) {
    // refresh the page, but no "reload" this time
    location.href = "www.example.com/incidents";
}
```

Or using Angular.js:

```
if ($location.search().reload === "true") {
    // refresh the page, but no "reload" this time
    $location.path("/incidents");
}
```

Alternatively, you could check for the existence of the cookie you set just before reloading the page. If the cookie is there, do not reload; if it isn't, set it and then reload the page:

```
if (!$cookies.get("Token")) {
    // set cookies, do whatever you need here
    
    // reload it only once
    $location.path("/incidents");
}
```

Comment: the "reload=true" where is used? my webpage is www.example.com/login and then the login send to me www.example.com/incidents and here is where I have my problem and I try to reload

Comment: `if ($location.search().reload === 'true') {
    $location.path('/mypage'); // refresh the page, but no "reload" this time
}` I think this is on my Incidents Controller?

Comment: Looks like when you call `/incidents` coming from `/login`, you should do it like `/incidents?reload=true`. Inside `/incidents` you will call `/incidents` again, but this time you will not pass the `reload` parameter.

Comment: @ErnestoRamirez for your second question, the answer is yes.

Comment: In your page URL, change it to www.example.com/incidents?reload=true

Comment: @LucioPaiva in fact I tried with the last option but the cookies exists, i thinks my problem is whit my factory, maybe the factory doesn't reads the cookies :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this... It's work!

```
var refresh = $window.localStorage.getItem('refresh');
console.log(refresh);
if (refresh===null){
    window.location.reload();
    $window.localStorage.setItem('refresh', "1");
}
```

Comment: This saved me some headaches. Thank you.